# Nautilus extensions written in Python does not run when it calls gtk.main()

Tags: python, pygtk, gnome, nautilus

I'm developing a nautilus extension and I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
import gtk
import pygtk
import nautilus
import gconf 
import gtk.glade

class Slide (nautilus.MenuProvider):    
f = None
def __init__(self):
    self.client = gconf.client_get_default()             
    self.f = gtk.glade.XML( "papel.glade" ) 
    self.window = self.f.get_widget("window1")        
    gtk.main()

def oi (self):                                
    self.window.show()

def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, file):
    self.oi()

def get_file_items(self, window, files):
    if len(files) != 1:
        return
        item = nautilus.MenuItem('NautilusPython::slide_file_item', 'Slide', 'Slide')
        item.connect('activate', self.menu_activate_cb, files[0])
    return item,

def get_background_items(self, window, file):
     item = nautilus.MenuItem('NautilusPython::slide_item', 'Slide', 'Slide')
     item.connect('activate', self.menu_background_activate_cb, file)
     return item, 

def menu_background_activate_cb(self, menu, file):
    self.oi()
```

The code does not work (Slide does not appear in the context menu). But if I comment the lines:

```
 self.f = gtk.glade.XML( "papel.glade" ) 
 self.window = self.f.get_widget("window1")        
 gtk.main()
```

then the code runs. I can't see any problem with those lines, any help?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does not work"?

Comment: Another suggestion would be to use gtk.Builder instead of gtk.glade.XML .

Answer (score 1):

Try only commenting gtk.main(). If it still runs after that I'm guessing that since nautilus is already running, calling gtk.main() launches a new gtk application. separate from nautilus. All you need to do is connect to nautilus and hit window.show(), which you do in your oi method.